# How does JAXB advance the XMLStreamReader?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to unmarshal objects from very large XML files using an XMLStreamReader.

If the XML elements I'm unmarshalling are separated (by a newline or even a single space) this works fine.

If the XML elements I'm unmarshalling do not have whitespace between them, I lose every other item - the XML reader seems to swallow the element after the one that gets unmarshalled.

Source for a simplified runnable example that demonstrates this is at https://gist.github.com/dalelane/88df784c3cb74b214d5c

The interesting bits are:

```
XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyJAXBClass.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

boolean running = true;
while (running){
    switch (reader.next()){
        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
            if (reader.getLocalName().equals("myunmarshallobjname")){
                JAXBElement<MyJAXBClass> unmarshalledObj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader, MyJAXBClass.class);
                MyJAXBClass item = unmarshalledObj.getValue();
            }
            break;
        case XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT:
            reader.close();
            running = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Every time the stream reader hits the start of an element, I pass it to the unmarshaller to unmarshall that fragment.

It works if I have XML with:

```
<myunmarshallobjname key="one"></myunmarshallobjname> <myunmarshallobjname key="two"></myunmarshallobjname>
```

But loses items if I have:

```
<myunmarshallobjname key="one"></myunmarshallobjname><myunmarshallobjname key="two"></myunmarshallobjname>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the reader to not skip over elements?

Comment: Is the problem in JAXB or in your code?  The element you are saying needs to be white space separated is the same one you are matching on in your if block.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is in my code - I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. But if I remove the unmarshall line, the START_ELEMENT event does fire for every element like I'd expect. With the unmarshall, it doesn't - I get a START_ELEMENT for every other element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double check which element event you are on after the unmarshal call.  If the `XMLStreamReader` is on `endElement` you will need to call `next()` as part of your loop, but it's on `startElement` you won't.

Comment: That's it, thank you! The end event after the unmarshal in my "working" case, was CHARACTERS - because the reader was pointing at the whitespace. So when I went round the loop and called reader.next() it moved me on to the start of the next element. In my broken case without the whitespace, the end event after the unmarshall was START_ELEMENT, as the reader was already pointing at the next element. I went round the loop, called reader.next() and skipped over it.

Comment: I shared a fixed version of my example in case it's helpful to the next person to try this. https://gist.github.com/dalelane/983f278d2485d29a6ef4

Comment: +1 - I never understood why `unmarshal(XMLStreamReader)` was specified the way it is.  When called with the reader positioned on a `START_ELEMENT` it would make far more sense in my mind for it to return with the reader pointing _at_ the corresponding `END_ELEMENT` rather than at the event _after_ it.  That way you wouldn't need to distinguish between the whitespace and no-whitespace cases, it'd always be safe to call `nextTag`.

Comment: @IanRoberts - I agree with you.  The behaviour you describe is what we originally did in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy), but then we changed it to match the reference implementation as that's what people were used to coding to.

Comment: It's nice to have my sanity checked by someone from the inner circle :-)