# I have noticed a buggy thing with xmlstreamreader. If the file is not pretty print, the stream reader misses some elements! why?? Look beneath

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, xmlstreamreader

I need to read generated xml files and I cant demand them to be in pretty format, It should not matter if the file is one long string or if its pretty with line breaks.

```
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeClass);
        final XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        final XMLStreamReader xmlr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(reader);

        xmlr.nextTag();
        List<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
        long count = 0;

        while (xmlr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(":"+XmlStreamUtils.printEvent(xmlr));
            int eventType = xmlr.next();

                if (eventType == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {

                    if (target.getSimpleName().equals(xmlr.getLocalName()) || target.getSimpleName().startsWith(xmlr.getLocalName())) {
                        items.add(unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlr, target).getValue());

                    }
                }


        }
```

file:
When jaxb and Xmlstreamreader unmarshal it will only unmarshal one Hest element even though there are two present. This only happens when its not pretty print. WHY??

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Fil>
    <Hest>
        <hestName>hest</hestName>
        <hestAge>12</hestAge>
        <hestColor>blue</hestColor>
    </Hest>
    <Hest>
        <hestName>hest</hestName>
        <hestAge>12</hestAge>
        <hestColor>blue</hestColor>
    </Hest>
</Fil>
```

My jaxb class

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package dk.skat.efi.wls.bebb.bum;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 * @author efidev
 *
 */
public class JaxbTest {
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Hest")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Hest {
        @XmlElement(name = "hestName")
        private String hestName;
        @XmlElement(name = "hestAge")
        private String hestAge;
        @XmlElement(name = "hestColor")
        private String hestColor;
        public String getHestName() {
            return hestName;
        }
        public void setHestName(String hestName) {
            this.hestName = hestName;
        }
        public String getHestAge() {
            return hestAge;
        }
        public void setHestAge(String hestAge) {
            this.hestAge = hestAge;
        }
        public String getHestColor() {
            return hestColor;
        }
        public void setHestColor(String hestColor) {
            this.hestColor = hestColor;
        }


    }
```

}

Comment: missing elements happens when unmarshalling with jaxb

Comment: Jaxb unmarshal and xmlstreamreader are buggy in java 7

Comment: look at this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551495/how-does-jaxb-advance-the-xmlstreamreader

Answer (score 0):

Make note of which event (node) the `XMLStreamReader` is at when the unmarshal operation is complete.  It may be one ahead of where you think it is.  This would mean your `next()` call would mean a nose gets skipped.

Comment: yes, the cursor will move to far after unmarshalling, BUT only when its not pretty format. If its pretty print then no problems at all. I need to support both situations.

Comment: @Elias - When a document is pretty printed there are extra text nodes present.  I don't see where a bug is present.  Your code will need to change so that it doesn't advance unnecessarily.

Comment: I cant see how to make it to support both cases. should I test the file first for pretty print and if it is not then take the extra nodes into account? what is a fine solution in this scenario?

Comment: the file size is like 700 mb or bigger

Comment: should it not catch the two startelements with the name BoernFamilieUdbetalingsSumStruktur not matter if its pretty or not. I compare with localname and simplename.I guess thats my confusion. thx a lot for your time

Comment: @Elias - Which element is being missed?  My assumption is that the local root that you want tonunmarshal is being missed, is this correct?  If so I believe you need to put some "if" logic around where you do the next call.

Comment: @Simplifying your question down to the minimun required to reproduce the issue also helps.

Comment: there two elements of BoernFamilieUdbetalingsSumStruktur in this example. It only catches the two elments when its pretty print, if one string then only one element. But the compare statement should catch elements no matter if its prettymor not. I making a simpler example now

Comment: @Elias - A simpler example is good.  What you should look at again though is for the non-pretty printed example examine what event you are on.  Then you will see that the next `next()` will advance you too far.  You will need to make that `next()` call conditional.  Does that make sense?

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Fil>
 <Hest>
  <hestName>hest</hestName>
  <hestAge>12</hestAge>
  <hestColor>blue</hestColor>
 </Hest>
 <Hest>
  <hestName>hest</hestName>
  <hestAge>12</hestAge>
  <hestColor>blue</hestColor>
 </Hest>
</Fil>

Comment: The compare section should catch the two hest elements but it does not when its not pretty print.

Comment: public class JaxbTest {
 @XmlRootElement(name = "Hest")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public static class Hest {
  @XmlElement(name = "hestName")
  private String hestName;
  @XmlElement(name = "hestAge")
  private String hestAge;
  @XmlElement(name = "hestColor")
  private String hestColor;
 
}

Comment: If should make next() conditional, like asking if you are to far? then if I am to far, I should go backwards?? how to do that

Comment: @Elias - You will never have to back up (you couldn't anyways), but you may not need to advance (as JAXB would have done this for you).  Step 1 is outputting the node you are at after the unmarshal is done.  Step 2 is realizing it is your code that is advancing the event too far.  Step 3 is making your next call conditional so it isn't called if you are already on the desired event.

Comment: @ step two. Why is my code advancing the event to far when its not pretty print. I hoped for consistency meaning that it will fail in both cases, pretty or not. Well I'll need to experiment some more then. thx alot for your input, I am really struggling to fix this

Comment: @Elias - Did you do step 1?

Comment: output from XmlStreamUtils.printEvent when its not pretty format:

Comment: :EVENT:[1][44] START_ELEMENT [<Hest>]
:EVENT:[1][50] START_ELEMENT [<hestName>]
:EVENT:[1][60] CHARACTERS [hest]
:EVENT:[1][64] END_ELEMENT [</hestName>]
:EVENT:[1][75] START_ELEMENT [<hestAge>]
:EVENT:[1][84] CHARACTERS [12]
:EVENT:[1][86] END_ELEMENT [</hestAge>]
:EVENT:[1][96] START_ELEMENT [<hestColor>]
:EVENT:[1][107] CHARACTERS [blue]
:EVENT:[1][111] END_ELEMENT [</hestColor>]
:EVENT:[1][123] END_ELEMENT [</Hest>]
:EVENT:[1][216] END_ELEMENT [</Fil>]

Comment: Can you just show the one evnt after the unmarshal is finished?

Comment: prettyformat: :EVENT:[2][1] START_ELEMENT [<Fil>]
:EVENT:[2][6] CHARACTERS [
 ]
:EVENT:[7][9] CHARACTERS [
 ]
:EVENT:[12][9] CHARACTERS [
]
:EVENT:[13][1] END_ELEMENT [</Fil>]

Comment: event after unmarshal:1

Comment: like this: :EVENT:[1][39] START_ELEMENT [<Fil>]
event after unmarshal:1
:EVENT:[1][130] START_ELEMENT [<Hest>]
:EVENT:[1][136] START_ELEMENT [<hestName>]
:EVENT:[1][146] CHARACTERS [hest]
:EVENT:[1][150] END_ELEMENT [</hestName>]
:EVENT:[1][161] START_ELEMENT [<hestAge>]
:EVENT:[1][170] CHARACTERS [12]
:EVENT:[1][172] END_ELEMENT [</hestAge>]
:EVENT:[1][182] START_ELEMENT [<hestColor>]
:EVENT:[1][193] CHARACTERS [blue]
:EVENT:[1][197] END_ELEMENT [</hestColor>]
:EVENT:[1][209] END_ELEMENT [</Hest>]
:EVENT:[1][216] END_ELEMENT [</Fil>]

Comment: it seems it rewinds it to the beginng of the first again....not sure I am doing it right

Comment: I will try to see if  I have the same problem when using XMLEventReader instead

Comment: https://eclipse.googlesource.com/eclipselink/eclipselink.runtime/+/6d2c63a4028e0b603635d52125487cf4874cf2af

Comment: Its skipping the first hest element from the start and only unmarshal the last hest element in the file when file is not pretty format